# API Design Questions using Django for OS tasks (REST vs RPC)

Tags: python, django, api, rest, rpc

Background:

I have an application that is supposed to automate some infrastructure & OS-heavy tasks that happen on a network file system (for example: mounting volumes, shutting down / bringing up servers, creating directories, moving data around, ssh-ing etc). Ultimately there are a lot of OS-level commands that need to be run in a sequence for each action. Our consumer/client likely does not know this sequence, but knows "I want to do X task".

Tech stack: Python/Django

I have been tasked with setting this application up but am perplexed on the best way to approach for modularity from the API standpoint & just overall design. Currently, we have a similar application that is a SOAP-style (rpc) but the way it is written is not very modular. Like for example, one function will have a ton of random hardcoded subprocess commands - not the approach I want to emulate here.

Initially I was leaning more towards REST API since Django has a nice django rest framework plug-in, but am having trouble modelling these very action-oriented tasks. The more I read other things online, the more I come to believe I really need to think of every little action as a resource with the client having to GET/POST/PUT to each of these to keep things very modular but when I boil that down further it looks like I may need to set up 15+ endpoints for each situation needed and the client likely isn't going to want to call all 15 endpoints to get their singular behavior they want. That being said - moving to rpc so users can have one endpoint that 'moves the moon on a single call' might not be the best approach either.

I think one of the issues I see is our application is doing a lot of work on a file system, not all contained within our application's database. I reckon that's kind of a central point of this application, but I have trouble modelling things that require file system actions outside our application's database.

Question 1:

One example action that our client might want to call would be responsible for ssh-ing to a remote server and running a command. How might you model this in REST?

Question 2:

How do you all model file system actions in your applications?

Question 3:

After reviewing the above, does RPC seem like the better option?

Other:

Any other help or feedback (even in generally is much appreciated).

Answer (score 0):

REST is similar to SOAP in a sense that you call operations in SOAP and REST just maps those operations to web resources and HTTP methods.

For example

```
z DoSSHStuffOnARemoteServer(x=1,y=2)
```

vs

```
POST /RemoteServer/SSHStuff {x:1,y:2}
```

If it timeouts, because it takes a lot of time, then you can do

```
202 accepted
{type: "transaction": href: "/RemoteServer/SSHStuff/123", status: "pending"}
```

and poll it in every 5-10 mins or use websockets to update the status. After it is done:

```
200 ok
{type: "transaction": href: "/RemoteServer/SSHStuff/123", status: "done", result: {z:3}}
```

So there is no magic. Just keep in mind that REST is in the presentation layer of your application, it returns view models and the entire structure is connected to the application services if you do DDD. It should not reflect the database structure unless you have an anemic domain model, or others call it thick client. Normally I would not say anything about `RemoteServer/SSHStuff`, just tell the client what will be done and stay silent about how it will be done. They don't need to know anything about how you store data or how many servers you have with what protocols and applications. It should not be their concern. The only thing they need to know what will be done, how long it takes to respond and what will be the response. The other part is irrelevant to them and it is a security risk if you share too much of it. When we design an interface like an interface for a REST service or just an OOP interface we always do it to hide implementation details. I hope that helps, have a nice day!